Как задать зумирование карту относительно выбранной точки/центра карты для текущей версии яндекс карь (v2)
Зум карты всегда происходит относительно позиции курсора на карте, а хотелось бы, чтобы зум всегда был относительно центра / выбранной точки, вне зависимости от положения курсора (как в Яндекс Маркете при активном табе Курьером, например) Есть ощущение, что для текущего релиза такое поведение не предусмотрено :( В ранних версиях можно было задавать параметры centering и position для setZoom
Миграцию на 3 версию карт не предлагать!

Вы уже потеряли вчерашний вопрос?

Я все еще не нашла ответа

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как задать зумирование карту относительно выбранной точки/центра карты?

Если вам обязательно зумить к центру, можно отключить штатный scrollZoom и реализовать свой механизм масштабирования так:
myMap.behaviors.disable(['scrollZoom']);    
myMap.events.add('wheel', function () {
  event.preventDefault()
  myMap.setZoom(myMap.getZoom()-event.deltaY/100)
});

